# What is the starting point for implementing MSAL into Java Web App?

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-msal

I currently have a Java web application that needs to have the MSAL implemented to sign in users (b2b).
I am confused on where to even begin after reading the documentation, can someone provide guidance please?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the official documentation to get familiar with the steps such as app registrations.

**Document address**: [Tutorial: Secure a Java web app using the Spring Boot Starter for Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory)

You want use msal(b2b), you can refer to [this source code and read readme file](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapp).

[Add Azure Active Directory B2B collaboration users in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/add-users-administrator)

You can also search for related keywords in youtube, for example: spring msal. Go find the right tutorial.